# How to stop WordPress from automatically turning letters into small or capital

Tags: css

I'm managing a client website (I did not build it).

What's happening is that WordPress is automatically changing letters into capital/small. Happens in front-end only.

This "Sophie Jane-Berney" turns into "Sophie Jane-**b**erney"  automatically when page loads. Notice the 'b'

These French words "Domaines d’activité" turn into "Domaines **D**’activité" automatically. Notice the 'D'.

For a second, they appear as they should, but as the page finishes loading, they change cases.

How can I stop that?

Comment: This is a css issue. Look for `text-transform: capitalize` in your css files

Comment: yes, that will be. search `text-transofrm` parameter and cancel them.

Comment: I know about the CSS property. It does not seem to be causing this.

Comment: You mentioned **for a second they appear as they should** so it should be a css issue

Comment: Using Developer Tools, if I do text-transform: none!important; to the "Domaines D’activité", nothing happens -- while in the back-end, it is entered as "Domaines d’activité"

Using same technique, nothing happens to "Sophie Jane-berney". I can however get the desired look by applying it text-transform: capitalize;. 

But what is causing this, to at least the "Domaines D’activité"? Because it will fix the issue with Sophie, but not with the French words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if there is any javascript issue that makes this things happen in your site. As per my understanding check your script.js or try by disabling plugins installes in your wordpress.

Comment: Yes, it was a javascript thing. Solved.

Comment: @ArslanFarooq It would be nice if you added some more details about the javascript which was causing this, so people having similar problems can get the solution here.

Comment: Of course, it was this code: https://gist.github.com/arslanfarooq/f6079b4442261ad67575ac282ec2c86b